# Convert From Access Query to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm trying to convert a report query from Access to SQL SERVER 2008. Using the same database but i can't get the same results. not even close. The Access query is like this:

```
SELECT Sum(INPUT_ItemSaleLines.TaxExclusiveTotal) AS TotalexTax,([TotalexTax])- Sum(    Nz([SumOfTaxExclusiveAmount])+ Nz([CostOfGoodsSoldAmount])+ Nz  
    (   
            Nz
            (   IIf
                (   Left([Input_Items.ItemNumber],5)='31-63',136*[Quantity]/1000,
                    IIf(Left([Input_Items.ItemNumber],6)='34S-63',200*[Quantity]/1000)
                )
            )+ Nz
            (   IIf
                (   Left([Input_Items.ItemNumber],5)='34-63',250*[Quantity]/1000,
                    IIf(Left([Input_Items.ItemNumber],6)='26-63',250*[Quantity]/1000)
                )
            )
        )
    ) AS Margin,    
    INPUT_Cards_1.Name AS SalesPerson, INPUT_Sales.SalesPersonID, 
    INPUT_Sales.InvoiceStatusID, INPUT_Cards.Name, INPUT_Items.ItemName, 
    Sum(INPUT_ItemSaleLines.Quantity) AS TotalQty, 
    Sum(INPUT_ItemSaleLines.CostOfGoodsSoldAmount) AS TotalCOGS, 
    Count(INPUT_Sales.SaleID) AS [Number of Sales], 
    Sum(qryShippingTotalexGST.SumOfTaxExclusiveAmount) AS ShippingTotal

FROM 
    (   qryShippingTotalexGST RIGHT JOIN 
        (
            (
                (   
                    INPUT_Items INNER JOIN INPUT_ItemSaleLines 
                    ON INPUT_Items.ItemID = INPUT_ItemSaleLines.ItemID
                ) INNER JOIN INPUT_Sales ON INPUT_ItemSaleLines.SaleID = INPUT_Sales.SaleID
            ) INNER JOIN INPUT_Cards ON INPUT_Sales.CardRecordID = INPUT_Cards.CardRecordID
        ) ON qryShippingTotalexGST.JobID = INPUT_ItemSaleLines.JobID
    ) LEFT JOIN INPUT_Cards AS INPUT_Cards_1 ON INPUT_Sales.SalesPersonID = INPUT_Cards_1.CardRecordID
WHERE 
    (((INPUT_Sales.Date) Between [Forms]![MenuReports]![StartDate] And [Forms]![MenuReports]![EndDate]))
GROUP BY INPUT_Items.ItemNumber,    
    INPUT_Cards_1.Name, INPUT_Sales.SalesPersonID, INPUT_Sales.InvoiceStatusID, 
    INPUT_Cards.Name, INPUT_Items.ItemName
HAVING 
    (((INPUT_Sales.InvoiceStatusID)<>"OR"));
```

Then the SQL Server script that i write like this:

```
SELECT MYOBItems.ItemName, MYOBCards.Name AS SalesPerson, MYOBCards1.Name, 
    SUM(MYOBsalesLines.Qty) AS TotalQty, 
    SUM(MYOBsalesLines.CostOfGoodsSoldAmount) AS TotalCOGS, 
    COUNT(MYOBSales.SaleID) AS NumberOfSales, 
    SUM(MYOBsalesLines.TaxExclusiveAmount) AS TotalexTax,
    SUM(cast(MYOBJobsShippingTotals.TaxExclusiveAmount AS Decimal(18,2))) AS ShippingTotal,
    (SUM(MYOBsalesLines.TaxExclusiveAmount)) - SUM
    (
        COALESCE(cast(MYOBJobsShippingTotals.TaxExclusiveAmount AS Decimal(18,2)),0)+ COALESCE(MYOBsalesLines.CostOfGoodsSoldAmount,0)+ COALESCE
        (
            COALESCE
            (   
                CASE 
                    WHEN LEFT(MYOBItems.ItemNumber,5) = '31-63' THEN (136*MYOBsalesLines.Qty/1000)
                    WHEN LEFT(MYOBItems.ItemNumber,6) = '34S-63' THEN (200*MYOBsalesLines.Qty/1000) 
                    ELSE 0
                END, 0                          
            )+ COALESCE
            (   
                CASE 
                    WHEN LEFT(MYOBItems.ItemNumber,5) = '34-63' THEN (250*MYOBsalesLines.Qty/1000)
                    WHEN LEFT(MYOBItems.ItemNumber,6) = '26-63' THEN (250*MYOBsalesLines.Qty/1000)  
                    ELSE 0  
                END , 0     
            ), 0
        )
    )AS Margin      
    , MYOBSales.InvoiceStatusID FROM 
    (   MYOBJobsShippingTotals RIGHT JOIN 
        (
            (
                (   
                    MYOBItems INNER JOIN MYOBsalesLines 
                    ON MYOBItems.ItemID = MYOBsalesLines.ItemID                     
                ) INNER JOIN MYOBSales ON MYOBsalesLines.SaleID = MYOBSales.SaleID
                    AND MYOBSales.ElevateCompanyID = MYOBsalesLines.ElevateCompanyID
            ) INNER JOIN MYOBCards AS MYOBCards1 ON MYOBSales.CardRecordID = MYOBCards1.CardRecordID
                AND MYOBsalesLines.ElevateCompanyID = MYOBCards1.ElevateCompanyID 
            AND MYOBSales.ElevateCompanyID = MYOBCards1.ElevateCompanyID
        ) ON MYOBJobsShippingTotals.JobID = MYOBsalesLines.JobID
    ) LEFT JOIN MYOBCards ON MYOBSales.SalesPersonID = MYOBCards.CardRecordID 
GROUP BY MYOBItems.ItemName, MYOBCards.Name,
    MYOBCards1.Name, MYOBSales.InvoiceStatusID
```

I suspect there was something wrong with the joined tables but not sure how to fix it.
Is there any mistake in my SQL Server script that is not relevant with the Access syntax?
Thank for the help in advance. and sorry for my long scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL server query is missing the WHERE and HAVING clauses of the MS Access query, it's GROUP BY clause doesn't have the same number or order of columns as the MS Access query, and has additional JOIN criteria that wasn't in the MS Access query.

A more faithful conversion would look like this:

```
SELECT SUM(MYOBsalesLines.TaxExclusiveAmount) AS TotalexTax
     , SUM(MYOBsalesLines.TaxExclusiveAmount)
       - SUM
         (
           COALESCE(cast(MYOBJobsShippingTotals.TaxExclusiveAmount AS Decimal(18,2)), 0)
           + COALESCE(MYOBsalesLines.CostOfGoodsSoldAmount,0)
           + COALESCE
             (
               COALESCE
               (   
                 CASE 
                   WHEN LEFT(MYOBItems.ItemNumber,5) = '31-63' THEN (136*MYOBsalesLines.Qty/1000)
                   WHEN LEFT(MYOBItems.ItemNumber,6) = '34S-63' THEN (200*MYOBsalesLines.Qty/1000) 
                   ELSE 0
                 END
                 , 0                          
               )
               + COALESCE
                 (   
                   CASE 
                     WHEN LEFT(MYOBItems.ItemNumber,5) = '34-63' THEN (250*MYOBsalesLines.Qty/1000)
                     WHEN LEFT(MYOBItems.ItemNumber,6) = '26-63' THEN (250*MYOBsalesLines.Qty/1000)  
                     ELSE 0  
                   END
                   , 0     
                 )
               , 0
             )
         )
       AS Margin
     , MYOBCards1.Name AS SalesPerson
     , MYOBSales.SalesPersonID
     , MYOBSales.InvoiceStatusID
     , MYOBCards.Name
     , MYOBItems.ItemName
     , SUM(MYOBsalesLines.Qty) AS TotalQty
     , SUM(MYOBsalesLines.CostOfGoodsSoldAmount) AS TotalCOGS
     , COUNT(MYOBSales.SaleID) AS NumberOfSales
     , SUM(cast(MYOBJobsShippingTotals.TaxExclusiveAmount AS Decimal(18,2))) AS ShippingTotal   
FROM 
(
    MYOBJobsShippingTotals RIGHT JOIN 
    (
        (
            (   
                MYOBItems INNER JOIN MYOBsalesLines 
                ON MYOBItems.ItemID = MYOBsalesLines.ItemID                     
            ) INNER JOIN MYOBSales ON MYOBsalesLines.SaleID = MYOBSales.SaleID
        ) INNER JOIN MYOBCards ON MYOBSales.CardRecordID = MYOBCards.CardRecordID
    ) ON MYOBJobsShippingTotals.JobID = MYOBsalesLines.JobID
) LEFT JOIN MYOBCards AS MYOBCards1 ON MYOBSales.SalesPersonID = MYOBCards1.CardRecordID
WHERE MYOBSales.Date BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY MYOBItems.ItemNumber
       , MYOBCards1.Name
       , MYOBSales.SalesPersonID
       , MYOBSales.InvoiceStatusID
       , MYOBCards.Name
       , MYOBItems.ItemName
HAVING MYOBSales.InvoiceStatusID <> 'OR'
```

Where the two question marks are your [Forms]![MenuReports]![StartDate] and [Forms]![MenuReports]![EndDate] values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it realy helped me.